# Can we change the schema in services module?

Tags: services

I am new to Drupal services; I have the below XML format, in which I need to expose nodes as services.

Can I do this using the Services module?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ngd:mediafile xmlns:ngd="http://www.xyzy.com/ngdine"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyzy.com/ngdine mediafile.xsd">
  <ngd:description>
    <![CDATA[This is the description]]>
  </ngd:description>
  <ngd:mediatype id="1"/>
  <ngd:internal>Aalborg city.JPG</ngd:internal>
</ngd:mediafile>
```

Can I change the schema?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to expose the output that way, THeres 2 ways you can do it. You can alter the response before it gets sent as a payload, or you can write your own Response Format.

Both should do what you need, but its merely a preference.

```
/**
 * Triggered when the REST server request a list of supported response formats.
 *
 * @param array $formatters
 *  An associative array of formatter info arrays keyed by type extension. The
 *  formatter info specifies an array of 'mime types' that corresponds to the
 *  output format; a 'view' class that is a subclass of RESTServerView; and
 *  'view arguments' that should be passed to the view when it is created;
 *  a 'model' can also be specified which the controller then must declare
 *  support for to be able to serve data in that format.
 * @return void
 */
 function hook_rest_server_response_formatters_alter(&$formatters) {
   /*
    * Sample modifications of the formatters array. Both yaml and
    * rss are formats that already are supported, so the changes are
    * nonsensical but illustrates the proper use of this hook.
    */

    // Add a Yaml response format.
    $formatters['yaml'] = array(
      'mime types' => array('text/plain', 'application/x-yaml', 'text/yaml'),
      'view' => 'RESTServerViewBuiltIn',
      'view arguments' => array('format' => 'yaml'),
    );

    // Add a Rss response format.
    $formatters['rss'] = array(
     'model' => 'ResourceFeedModel',
     'mime types' => array('text/xml'),
     'view' => 'RssFormatView',
    );
 }
```

The altering of the response is, function HOOK_services_request_postprocess_alter

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it is correct.

Comment: I used this solution and it worked for me, looking at `rest_server.views.inc` in the Services module helped.  In the case of XML you just need to create a formatter, and then copy the class `RESTServerViewBuiltIn` and `render_xml()` to a custom module and change it to suit the schema you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Besides retrieving content as XML, do you need any other functionality provided by the Services module?  If not, it might be overkill.

One simple alternative might be to write a module that implements [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/hook_menu) to define a menu item for a wildcard path such as `node/%/xml`, which then, in its page callback, outputs the XML in your specified format.

In Drupal 7, you might do this as follows:

```
<?php

function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['node/%nid/xml'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_xml_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_xml_view($nid) {
  drupal_set_header('Content-Type: text/xml');

  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  echo '<ngd:mediafile ...>';
  echo '<nid>' . $nid . '</nid>';
  // ...
  echo '</ngd:mediafile>';

  drupal_exit();
}
```

Then, after enabling the new module, you can retrieve XML content by simply fetching, for example, URL http://example.com/node/42/xml .

Comment: What are those last three functions for?  module_invoke_all('exit');
  session_write_close();
  exit();

Comment: @cdmo: Drupal will, by default, try to render a themed page.  Instead of doing that, we want to provide output directly, then stop Drupal from doing its thing.  Those 3 invocations take care of that.  (Edit: I just replaced it with `drupal_exit()`, which is a simpler way of achieving the same.)